# web app engine / google plugin: creating an backend for your Android app

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I'm trying to use the Google Plugin to create a Web API backend as shown in this video:

[Building web API's for Android](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=dylFNrvZ_3U#!/)
seen from 26:50 until 39:40

I am able to start a local version of my App Engine and insert / get data to and from it using curl, as shown on this website: http://ido-green.appspot.com/CloudEndpoints/CloudEndpointsWebBlogPost.html

I have no experience with Web Apps whatsoever, but so the first mentioned video and wanted to experiment with it. So I want an Android app with Web App Engine as backend.

Now, I deployed it using the Google plugin and then went to https://my-application-id.appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer

That should give me some api, but nothing is there! If I go to

https://my-application-id.appspot.com, it says 'not found'. I went to https://appengine.google.com/ and there my application is shown. Clicking on 'backends', it says there are none.

I've been searching online quite some hours now, I cannot get a decente example how to handle this.

Is there someone with experience on this?

> edit: when I go to localhost:8888/_ah/admin/backends it says "This application doesn't define any backends. See the documentation for more."

So what actually is my biggest question: why does .appspot.com/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis give 'not found' back? I should have an API now

Comment: try going to localhost:8888/_ah/api/explorer.  The "backends" in the admin refers to a type of server (ie, frontend vs backend), which is not what you're looking for.  The new REST API thing is called "endpoints".  There's a lot of holes in your question, you may not have deployed properly or there might be a typo in your code.  It's much easier to test locally first.

Comment: going to the localhost explorer also gives 'not found'. Am I missing something for 'endpoints'?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new application on GoogleAppEngine, and provide a unique ID for it. For example raptor3000app, and then you can access it via https://raptor3000app.appspot.com

edit: 
you can do it here: https://appengine.google.com/

Comment: Yes, I have created an own id and put it instead of the my-application-id part in the appspot.com url. Going to appengine.google.com it shows my information

Comment: No, it didn't help. What I meant is that I have done this already. Sorry